# How long would it take for a tank of same-spin hydrogen atoms to become a tank of H₂?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spin

In the question
[Is there an energy cost associated with flipping the spin of an electron?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9743/), it is shown that it is very unlikely for two hydrogen atoms to bond if their electrons have the same spin. The reason is the very low rate at which such a system would be able to emit photons. This makes me think that a bottle of $\ce{H1}$ could be prepared if the spin-up hydrogen was separated from the spin-down hydrogen with an apparatus like the one used in the Stern-Gerlach experiment. Is it true that the spin transition can be ignored for "all practical purposes"  ([see linked question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9743/)), or can tanks of spin-aligned $\ce{H1}$ only exist for times uninterestingly short for chemical purposes?

Comment: Not long at all.

Comment: Assuming the tank survives ...

Comment: I doubt this experiment would be a valid "practical purpose". ;) Also spin relaxation typically occurs via energy exchange with the "lattice", not photon emission. Unless your tank had no walls and its content was infinitely dilute, it would present a suitably solid lattice for your electrons.

Comment: And wouldnt one stray 21/cm photon self amplify like crazy?

Comment: @Karl What if the vessel was lined with a compound that only exposed "spin-saturated" atoms to the gas, atoms whose electrons could not possibly accept any more spin? Is such a material possible?

Comment: Hm, nonradiative interactions *can* change the spin without restrictions, as far as I understand.